# While Loops Python- No error why?

Tags: python, while-loop

Why does the following code not throw an error?

```
while 7:
    print ("Hi")
```

Instead, it prints "Hi" forever.

Comment: Well, 7 is true-like, so it should print ("Hi") forever.

Comment: And why do you think it should throw and error? I have a nice little program on my computer that prints "y" forever, and [it comes in handy sometimes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command)

Comment: Errors aren't generated *every* time a computer has problems. And Python in particular will allow you to do more than other, stricter languages because Python expects you to know what you're doing. I do use `while True` quite a bit myself.

Answer (score 4):

Because the expression `7` is considered true in a boolean context (like a `while` test).

All non-zero numbers are true in a boolean context. So are non-empty strings, and non-empty lists, tuples or dictionaries.

Basically, anything that is not empty, not `None` or `False` and not numerical zero is considered a true value. See [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is non-zero is interpreted as True, so while(7) is synonymous with while(1), which is an infinite loop

Comment: @RobFoley That is completely incorrect. `bool(-1)` is `True`.

Comment: @RobFoley: no, `-1` is considered true. See the documentation I link to in my answer.

Comment: I thought so too, but I just did -1 == True in Python 3.4's console and it returned false. 1== True returned true. Perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: You're comparing the integers, rather than the truthiness of the integers.

Comment: Yeah I realized that as I said it.

Comment: @RobFoley -1==True is false due to that it checks if True and -1 are same it isn't because numerically True is 1 int(True) prints 1

Answer (score 0):

While loops only take `True` or `False` conditions, for example:

```
While 1:
    print("hi")
```

Because 1 is considered `True` the loop becomes infinte

If you would like the program to `print("hi")` 7 times you need a `for` loop:

They work like this:

```
for i in range(7):
    print("hi")
```

`i` is merely a variable and `range(7)` is just the amount of times you would like to loop